# Write bool expression to tell if a list is increasing

Tags: c++, list, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have the program below given and I was able to complete the assignment to a certain point except in adding a menu option that gives a true/false return if the given list is increasing or decreasing 
For example, for a list containing head-() (11) (8) (15) (3), isIncreasing() should return false. However, it would return true when working on a list containing head- () (7) (9) (15).

How would I look at the list and tell the program to compare the values and make this determination

The assignment tells us that this new operation should have the signature:

bool List::isIncreasing() const;

LIST.H

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H
#include <iostream>
#include "ListNode.h"
#include "ListIterator.h"

namespace cs20 {

template <class Object>
class List {
public:
    List();
    List( const List& rhs );
    ~List();

    bool isEmpty() const;
    void makeEmpty();
    ListIterator<Object> zeroth() const;
    ListIterator<Object> first() const;
    void insert( const Object& data,
                 const ListIterator<Object> &iter );
    void insert( const Object& data );
    ListIterator<Object> findPrevious( const Object& data ) const;
    void remove( const Object& data );

    const List& operator =( const List& rhs );
private:
    ListNode<Object> * head;

};

}
#endif
```

LIST.CPP

```
#ifndef LIST_CPP
#define LIST_CPP

#include "List.h"

namespace cs20 {
template <class Object>
List<Object>::List() {
    head = new ListNode<Object>;
}

template <class Object>
List<Object>::List( const List<Object>& rhs ) {
    head = new ListNode<Object>;
    *this = rhs;
}

template <class Object>
List<Object>::~List() {
    makeEmpty();
    delete head;
}

template <class Object>
bool List<Object>::isEmpty() const {
    return( head->nextIsNull() );
}

template <class Object>
void List<Object>::makeEmpty() {
    while (!isEmpty()) {
        remove( first().retrieve() );
    }
}

template <class Object>
ListIterator<Object> List<Object>::zeroth() const {
    return( ListIterator<Object>( head ) );
}

template <class Object>
ListIterator<Object> List<Object>::first() const {
    return( ListIterator<Object>( head->getNext() ) );
}

template <class Object>
void List<Object>::insert( const Object& data,
                           const ListIterator<Object> &iter ) {
    if (iter.isValid()) {
        ListNode<Object>* newnode = new ListNode<Object>( data, iter.current->getNext() );
        iter.current->setNext( newnode );
    }
}

template <class Object>
void List<Object>::insert( const Object& data ) {
    // insert after the header node
    ListNode<Object>* newnode = new ListNode<Object>( data, head->getNext() );
    head->setNext( newnode );
}

template <class Object>
ListIterator<Object> List<Object>::findPrevious( const Object& data ) const {
    ListNode<Object>* node = head;
    while( node->getNext() != NULL && node->getNext()->getElement() != data ) {
        node = node->getNext();
    }
    if (node->getNext() == NULL) {
        node = NULL;
    }
    return ListIterator<Object>( node );
}

template <class Object>
void List<Object>::remove( const Object& data ) {
    ListIterator<Object> iter = findPrevious( data );
    if (iter.isValid()) {
        ListNode<Object>* node = findPrevious( data ).current;
        if (node->getNext() != NULL) {
            ListNode<Object> *oldNode = node->getNext();
            node->setNext( node->getNext()->getNext() );  // Skip oldNode
            delete oldNode;
        }
    }
}

// Deep copy of linked list
template <class Object>
const List<Object>& List<Object>::operator =( const List<Object>& rhs ) {
    if (this != &rhs) {
        makeEmpty();

        ListIterator<Object> rightiter = rhs.first( );
        ListIterator<Object> myiterator = zeroth();
        while( rightiter.isValid() ) {
            insert( rightiter.retrieve(), myiterator );
            rightiter.advance();
            myiterator.advance();
        }
    }
    return( *this );
}

}

#endif
```

IMPLEMENTATION
LISTMENU.CPP

// Menu.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

```
#include <iostream>
#include "List.h"
#include "ListNode.h"
#include "ListIterator.h"
#include "List.cpp"
#include "ListNode.cpp"
#include "ListIterator.cpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cs20;

enum CHOICE {MAKEEMPTY, REMOVE, ISEMPTY, FINDPREVIOUS, INSERT, QUIT, PRINT };

CHOICE menu();
void printList( const List<int>& l );

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int value;
    List<int> list;
    ListIterator<int> iter;

    CHOICE choice;
    do {
        choice = menu();
        switch( choice ) {
        case MAKEEMPTY:
            list.makeEmpty();
            break;
        case ISEMPTY:
            if (list.isEmpty()) {
                cout << "list is empty" << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << "list is not empty" << endl;
            }
            break;
        case REMOVE:
            cout << "Please provide int to remove: ";
            cin  >> value; 
            list.remove( value );
            break;
        case INSERT:
            cout << "Please provide int to insert: ";
            cin  >> value; 
            list.insert( value );
            break;
        case FINDPREVIOUS:
            cout << "Please provide int to find: ";
            cin  >> value; 
            iter = list.findPrevious( value );
            if (iter.isValid()) {
                cout << "previous element = " << iter.retrieve() << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << "data element was not found!" << endl;
            }
            break;
        case PRINT:
            printList( list );
            break;
        case QUIT:
            break;
    }   

    } while (choice != QUIT);

    return( 0 );
}

int sample() {
    cout << "Forming Lists" << endl;
    int one = 1, two = 2;
    List<int> l1 = List<int>();
    List<int> l2 = List<int>();

    l1.insert( one );
    l1.insert( two );

    cout << "print l1" << endl;
    printList( l1 );

    cout << "l2 = l1" << endl;
    l2 = l1;

    cout << "print l2" << endl;
    printList( l2 );    

    cout << "l1.remove(one)" << endl;
    l1.remove( one );

    cout << "print l1" << endl;
    printList( l1 );

    cout << "print l2" << endl;
    printList( l2 );
    cout << "findPrevious 1 in l2" << endl;
    ListIterator<int> iter = l2.findPrevious( one );
    if (iter.isValid()) {
        cout << "--iter valid" << endl;
        cout << iter.retrieve() << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "--iter not valid" << endl;
    }

    cout << "findPrevious 2 in l2" << endl;
    iter = l2.findPrevious( two );
    if (iter.isValid()) {
        cout << "--iter valid" << endl;
        cout << iter.retrieve() << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "--iter not valid" << endl;
    }

    cout << "findPrevious 1 in l1" << endl;
    iter = l1.findPrevious( one );
    if (iter.isValid()) {
        cout << "--iter valid" << endl;
        cout << iter.retrieve() << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "--iter not valid" << endl;
    }

    cout << "findPrevious 2 in l1" << endl;
    iter = l1.findPrevious( two );
    if (iter.isValid()) {
        cout << "--iter valid" << endl;
        cout << iter.retrieve() << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "--iter not valid" << endl;
    }

    cout << "print l1" << endl;
    printList( l1 );    

        // you can remove whatever you want, whether it exists or not
    cout << "l1.remove(one)" << endl;
    l1.remove( one );

    cout << "print l1" << endl;
    printList( l1 );    

    return( 0 );
}

void printList( const List<int>& l ) {
    if (l.isEmpty())
        cout << "Empty list" << endl;
    else {
        ListIterator<int> iter = l.first();
        while (iter.isValid()) {
            cout << iter.retrieve() << " -> ";
            iter.advance();
        }
        cout << "NULL";
        cout << endl;
    }
}

CHOICE menu() {
    char choice;
    CHOICE result;
    cout << "(M)akeEmpty I(s)Empty (R)emove (I)nsert (F)indPrevious (P)rint (Q)uit: " << endl;
    cin  >> choice;
    switch( choice ) {
    case 'M':
    case 'm':
        result = MAKEEMPTY;
        break;
    case 'S':
    case 's':
        result = ISEMPTY;
        break;
    case 'R':
    case 'r':
        result = REMOVE;
        break;
    case 'I':
    case 'i':
        result = INSERT;
        break;
    case 'F':
    case 'f':
        result = FINDPREVIOUS;
        break;
    case 'Q':
    case 'q':
        result = QUIT;
        break;
    case 'P':
    case 'p':
        result = PRINT;
        break;
    }

    return( result );
}
```

Comment: First of all, you can't define those templates in a different translation unit from where they're used, and including a cpp file from a user file is very odd. If you want them in a cpp, include it at the bottom of the header. Secondly, provide iterators and use `std::is_sorted`.

Comment: it can be done in O(1) - just check if inserted item is greater or equal to previous item and is less or equal than next one. Remove items will not break the sorted invariant of the list.

Comment: @chris how might i implement that?

Comment: Basically you'd need a `begin()` and `end()` method that return iterators.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the first link:

1. Record the value of the current link
2. Iterate to the next link
3. Test if it is greater than (or equal to) the value of the previous link's recorded value
4. If yes, repeat from 1.
5. Else return false

If you get all the way through the list, you know the list is increasing all the way through.